# Toyota Avensis Intake Manifold Rattle Fix - quesion about gasket

Tags: engine, toyota, air-intake

I have a Toyota Avensis which has the intake manifold rattle problem. I asked the dealer for a price on the new part and he quoted me €400. From a breakers yard they are hard to get and the going rate seems to be around €100, which is not in my budget at the moment.

So I found [this article](http://gorup-sinkovec.net/diy/rattling-noise-in-toyota-corolla-intake-manifold-solved/)  and even though it's a bit unorthodox; it seems to have worked for many people and I would like to give it a go. My only question is about the gasket, and whether I'd really need to replace it or not. I have seen pictures of people taking off intake manifolds and the gaskets rarely seem to be damaged. I am on a very tight budget so I'd like to avoid buying the gasket if at all possible, but still I know the gasket is relatively cheap so I don't want to be unwise. What is the norm? Do mechanics routinely not replace intake manifolds or is it a case that you would replace it even if it looked OK?

The car is 2002 and has about 150,000 miles on the clock.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of intake manifold gasket, if there is absolutely no damage to the rubber it should be good for reuse. You will need to be *very* careful with it when taking it off of the engine. Make sure you clean it up and put a *very* light coat of clean oil on it before installation. Do not remove it from the intake manifold to do this, though, as you run the risk of damaging it. Only mess with it as much as you need to and no more.